# How a sort associative array bash script

Tags: bash, sorting, associative

How do I sort an associative array in bash?

For example, I have array in bash:

```
[0,0]="Max"
[0,1]="25"
[1,0]="Vladimir"
[1,1]="0"
[2,0]="Mayki"
[2,1]="50"
```

Output must be:

1. Mayki - 50
2. Max - 25
3. Vladimir - 0

I don't know how sort this array.

Additional Info: I parse assoc array from text file ("log.txt")

```
    #!/bin/bash

declare -A b_array

# Read the file in parameter and fill the array named "array"
getArray() {

    i=0
    w=9

    count=10

    while read line # Read a line
    do
        k=0
        #array[i]=$line # Put it into the array

        #b_array[$i,0]=$(grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" <<<"$line") 

        for word in $line;
          do  
                  #echo $k;
                  #echo $word;
                  if [ "$k" = "$w" ]; then
                      if [ $word != "-" ]; then
                        b_array[$i]=$word 
                        i=$(($i + 1))
                      fi 

                  fi 
                  k=$(($k + 1))
            done


    done < $1
}

getArray "log.txt"
```

Comment: You're better off using a language with better data structure support.

Comment: What does the input actually look like? What does that example array have to do with anything? You aren't creating one like that (bash can't do it). You don't appear to have one like that in the input (though that isn't at all clear). Associative arrays don't have an order so the best you could do is fetch and sort the keys and then loop over that sorted list of keys.

Comment: It my homework of KPI University

Comment: The original mission:
I need to parse the file and display 10 lines of queries by the number of bytes.

Comment: @EtanReisner (bash can't do what?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Create a multi-dimensional array. You can use those strings as associative indices manually though (as you did in your answer).

Comment: This is a really odd way to use an associative array. One would usually use the name as the key: `([Max]=25 [Mayki]=50 [Vladimir]=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to this problem. One of the easiest is probably to read the pairs of strings into an indexed array and then reverse numeric sort on the number field:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
declare -a sa

arr[0,0]="Max"
arr[0,1]="25"
arr[1,0]="Vladimir"
arr[1,1]="0"
arr[2,0]="Mayki"
arr[2,1]="50"

## convert associative array to 
#  indexed array of string pairs
#  (e.g. "Max - 25", "Mayki - 50" )
for i in ${!arr[@]}; do                         # for each key in ar

    x=${i%,*}                                   # separate x,y values
    y=${i#*,}
    (( y == 1 )) && continue                    # if y == 1, continue

    for j in ${!arr[@]}; do                     # for each key in ar

        _x=${j%,*}                              # separate _x,_y values
        _y=${j#*,}
        ((x != _x)) || ((_y == 0)) && continue  # if x != _x, or _y == 0, continue

        sa+=( "${arr[$i]} - ${arr[$j]}" )       # add combined string to indexed sa

    done
done

sort -r -k3 -n <<<"$(printf "%s\n" "${sa[@]}")" # numeric reverse sort sa on key3

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash sort_assoc.sh
Mayki - 50
Max - 25
Vladimir - 0
```

Comment: What errors? I have `GNU bash, version 4.3.33` There are other ways to sort the indexed array if that is giving you problems. I checked, also works on `GNU bash, version 4.2.37` (oldest I have)

Comment: : No such file or directoryh
: command not found
': not a valid identifier `ar
': not a valid identifier `sa
: command not found
: command not found
sort.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file
-bash-4.1$

Comment: What? are you sure you copied/pasted it exactly? Let's change `ar` to `arr` to not conflict with the external `ar` command (which it shouldn't anyway) Try it now.

Comment: Sorry, check the code on the server console VPS (4.1).
It is still on the virtual machine will try to run (4.3).

Comment: Ok, it works perfectly. I've ran in on multiple machines (Archlinux & openSuSE) to confirm. The `ar ': not a valid identifier` and `sa : command not found : command not found sort.sh: line 36` errors make No sense. There is something suspect with your shell interpreter if you are getting those errors. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: borysov@borysov-virtual-machine:~$ sh sort.sh
sort.sh: 3: sort.sh: declare: not found
sort.sh: 4: sort.sh: declare: not found
sort.sh: 6: sort.sh: max[0,0]=Max: not found
sort.sh: 7: sort.sh: max[0,1]=25: not found
sort.sh: 8: sort.sh: max[1,0]=Vladimir: not found
sort.sh: 9: sort.sh: max[1,1]=0: not found
sort.sh: 10: sort.sh: max[2,0]=Mayki: not found
sort.sh: 11: sort.sh: max[2,1]=50: not found
sort.sh: 28: sort.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")"

Comment: `bash` not `sh`. How are you attempting to run this? What the heck is `sort.sh`?? Your bash script doesn't recognize `declare`? That is all impossible. Just copy/paste the script into a file. Say `mytest.sh`. Then simply type `bash mytest.sh`. It will work, I promise... If you copied/pasted into `sort.sh`, then just type `bash sort.sh` or make it executable by `chmod 0755 sort.sh` and then type `./sort.sh` (or whatever you named the file) All this presumes you do not have stray control characters like carriage returns or some other nonsense in the file.

Comment: `borysov@borysov-virtual-machine:~$ sh sort.sh` No No No... It will not run under `sh` it is a `BASH` script, just like your tag said. `sh` is the POSIX shell (derived from the old Bourne Shell) and lacks almost all features that make Bash -- Bash.

Comment: Thank you so much, never have thought that I was so quick to help. My mistake in the rights to the file. 755 put all examples work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably switch to Perl for such a complicated task, even if it's still doable in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
arr=([0,0]="Max"
     [0,1]="25"
     [1,0]="Vladimir"
     [1,1]="0"
     [2,0]="Mayki"
     [2,1]="50"
     [10,0]=Ivan
     [10,1]=10
    )

indices=( $( (IFS=$'\n' ; echo "${!arr[*]}") | grep ,0 | cut -d, -f1 | sort ) )

for i in "${indices[@]}" ; do
    echo ${arr[$i,0]} ${arr[$i,1]}
done | sort -rnk2
```

It would be much simpler if you defined the array like

```
arr=([Max]=25
     [Vladimir]=0
     [Mayki]=50
     [Ivan]=10
    )

for paren in "${!arr[@]}" ; do
    echo $paren ${arr[$paren]}
done | sort -rnk2
```

Comment: I have error: 
: command not found
': not a valid identifier: `arr
: command not found
: command not found
'est3.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'est3.sh: line 16: `for i in "${indices[@]}" ; do

Comment: @МаксимБорисов: What version of bash?

Comment: @МаксимБорисов: It should work. Did you copy and paste the code?

Comment: @МаксимБорисов: Blocked here :-(

Comment: @МаксимБорисов: Can't access either :-(

Comment: Thank you so much guys put right 755 - it's my fault. Now everything works as it should!