# Read in and parse textfile

Tags: bash, parsing, sorting

I need to parse the file (txt) and display 10 lines of queries by the number of bytes. (sort) I have a file *log.txt*:

```
164.94.76.83.cust.bluewin.ch - - [17/Oct/2006:07:56:45 -0700] "GET /example/serif.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4824 "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060909 Firefox/1.5.0.7"
164.94.76.83.cust.bluewin.ch - - [03/Oct/2006:07:56:45 -0700] "GET /example/example.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6685 "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060909 Firefox/1.5.0.7"
164.94.76.83.cust.bluewin.ch - - [06/Oct/2006:07:56:46 -0700] "GET /example/When/200x/2003/07/25/Nuke.png HTTP/1.1" 200 19757 "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060909 Firefox/1.5.0.7"
164.94.76.83.cust.bluewin.ch - - [15/Oct/2006:07:56:46 -0700] "GET /example/When/200x/2003/07/25/diablo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 12597 "http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2003/07/25/NotGaming" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.8.0.7) Gecko/20060909 Firefox/1.5.0.7"
164.94.76.83.cust.bluewin.ch - - [19/Oct/2006:07:56:46 -0700] "GET /example/When/200x/2003/07/25/-big/Nuke.jpg HTTP/1.1" 403 322 "
```

Output must be (with count in % and links - and sort DESC):

```
1. http://www.example.org/example/When/200x/2006/09/25/ - 3100 - 74%                                                    
2. http://www.example.org/example/ - 1000 - 24%                
3. http://www.example.org/example/genx/docs/Guide.html - 91 - 2%
```

That is, it is necessary to highlight the line for the maximum number of bytes in the request sort and indicate the amount of interest.

Comment: @OP- I guess you wanted proper alignment of your output in a line-by-line order!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I can help you, but it would help if you have already written some of the script.

Comment: See more I create but I dont know - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850406/how-a-sort-associative-array-bash-script/29851747?noredirect=1#comment47831675_29851747

Comment: wow, that's a long read! In your original comments somewhere, you say, "The original mission: I need to parse the file and display 10 lines of queries by the number of bytes. "  I think there are easier ways to do that than what you have tried so far. I will try to come up with a better way today.

Comment: Yes I write sh script but I know that not the easiest way. There are ways for certain simple.

Comment: Do you have perl or python installed?  It would be a heck of a lot easier in one of those languages.

Comment: Use only Shell any programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you insist on a shell-only approach, the closest solution to what you ask seems to be something like this:

```
sort -t ' ' -k 10 -r -n log.txt | head -n 10 | awk '{print $1 $7, $10}'
```

You can probably do (much) better by either setting a more useful `LogFormat` when logging the requests, or by allowing a Perl or Python parser when processing the logs.

Comment: Wow! I've been writing scripts and it is all on one line. Tell me more as a percentage?

Comment: As you'll fine out, the line above is very fragile.  Don't use it for anything serios, it can break in countless ways.  As for the percentage, it isn't clear what you want.  Percentage from what?  What is supposed to be 100%?

Comment: Sorry, I have bad English.
percentages:
The number of bytes downloaded for each of them as a percentage of the total
the number of bytes downloaded for dealing with these referrers

Comment: sort -t ' ' -k 10 -r -n log.txt | head -n 10 | awk '{print NR". " $11 " - " $10}'

Comment: Made as it is necessary only stayed interest which wrote above. Very grateful for the help of good people.

Comment: percentages on the amount (of 10 records)